# What is the Ito equation of $ \ddot{x}(t)+\kappa x(t)=h \dot{B}(t) + \ddot{B}(t) $?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $B(t)$ be a 1-dimensional Brownian motion. Consider the equation
$$
\ddot{x}(t)+\kappa x(t)=h \dot{B}(t) \quad \text { on } t \geq 0
$$
where $\kappa$ and $h$ are positive constants. By introducing the new variable $y(t)=\dot{x}(t)$, the corresponding Itô equation is
$$
d\left[\begin{array}{l}
x(t) \\
y(t)
\end{array}\right]=A\left[\begin{array}{l}
x(t) \\
y(t)
\end{array}\right] d t+\left[\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
h
\end{array}\right] d B(t)
$$
where
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
-\kappa & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
But what if we add the second derivative of Brownian motion to the equation? I mean, e.g.:
$$
\ddot{x}(t)+\kappa x(t)=h \dot{B}(t) + \ddot{B}(t) \quad \tag{*}
$$
What is the corresponding Ito equation of (*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One variant: To reduce the order in the equation, combine the derivative terms. The substitution will then also have lower order derivatives.
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\dot x-hB-\dot B)+x=0
$$
Thus set $\dot x=v+hB+\dot B$
to get $\dot v+κx=0$ or more well-defined in shortened Ito integral form
$$
dx = (v+hB)\,dt+dB
\\
dv=-κx\,dt.
$$
One could shift some terms around to get other first-order systems, here mainly reducing the substitution to $\dot x=v+\dot B$ so that $\dot v+κx=h\dot B$ or
$$
dx=v\,dt+dB\\dv = -κx\,dt+h\,dB
$$